# Scrolling custom BoxLayout in kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, vertical-scrolling

I've created my own BoxLayout element

from .kv file:

```
<StageBox>
orientation: 'horizontal'
spacing: 2
BoxLayout:
    id: HoursBox
    size_hint: .045,1
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing:1
Cell:
    id: StageCell
    text: ''
    size_hint: .09,1
GridLayout:
    id: GridBox
    spacing: 1
    cols: 30
    rows: 12
```

In my main window i created some BoxLayout (vertical) to arrange my "StageBox" elements which will be 6-8 in line. Its pretty a lot and i really need my root BoxLayout to be scrollable!

I cant find information how to use ScrollView or RecycleView with custom BoxLayout ( in my case)

As u can see in the image i replaced 3 instances of my StageBox, but as i said i need some scrollview to replace more of them without squeezing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My main.py code

```
class StageBox(BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()

class MainApp(App):
    stageList = ('item1', 'item2','item3')  #BUT THERE WILL BE MORE

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (.80,.80,.80,1)
        Window.size = (1350, 780)

        # HEADER PART  (NON SCROLLABLE)
        TABLE = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', spacing = 4, padding = 10)
        HEADER = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal', size_hint = [1,.08], spacing = 2)
        HEADER.add_widget(Cell(text='HOURS', size_hint = [.045,1]))
        HEADER.add_widget(Cell(text='STAGE', size_hint = [.09,1]))
        DataBox = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', spacing = 2)
        DataBox.add_widget(Cell(text = 'June'.upper()))
        DaysBox = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal', spacing = 1)
        for i in range(1,31):
            DaysBox.add_widget(Cell(text = str(i)))
        DataBox.add_widget(DaysBox)
        HEADER.add_widget(DataBox)
        TABLE.add_widget(HEADER)

        # BODY PART  SCROLLABLE !
        scroll = RV()
        BODY = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical',spacing = 4)
        for item in self.stageList:
            SB = StageBox()
            Boxy = SB.ids.HoursBox
            for i in range(1,13):
                Boxy.add_widget(Cell(text=str(i)))
            Grid = SB.ids.GridBox
            for i in range(1,361):
                Grid.add_widget(Button(text='', background_color = self.whiteColor, background_normal = ''))
            Stage = SB.ids.StageCell
            Stage.text = item
            BODY.add_widget(SB)

        TABLE.add_widget(BODY)
        return TABLE


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```